# Connecting vectors for two different congruences?

Tags: general-relativity, geodesics

So I was reading this [thesis](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/25218619.pdf). It presents this equation I haven't seen (Page $2$ equation $6$) before and have no idea how to derive:

> The general solution to this second-order differential equation along
> any geodesic $\gamma$ will have two arbitrary constants (corresponding
> to the different congruences of geodesics that might have $\gamma$ as
> a member). There is a first integral along any geodesic that relates
> the connecting vectors for two different congruences which have one
> central geodesic curve (with affine parameter $v$) in common. This is
>
> $$ \eta_{1a} \frac{\delta \eta_2^a}{\delta v} - \eta_{2a} \frac{\delta \eta_1^a}{\delta v} = \text{constant}$$
> and is completely independent of the curvature of the spacetime manifold.

Where $\eta_a$ is the deviation vector and $v$ is the time and what is the physical/geometric interpretation of the constant?

Comment: If $\eta_1$, $\eta_2$ are deviation vectors from $\gamma$ connecting it to nearby geodesics $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ respectively, then this particular quantity gives a measure of relative twist b/w these geodesics and it is independent of the total curvature. An accurate geometric interpretation for null geodesics is given in section 7.4 of Spinors and space-time Vol-II.  It is also closely related (for null geodesics) with the classical symplectic 2-form $\Sigma=dP\wedge dx$ for mass-less particles

Comment: @KP99 besides Spinors and space-time Vol-II is there any other place I can read upon the "relative twist"? (I'd have to first go through volume $1$) A quick google gave me nothing :/ As always thanks!

Comment: I'll mention if I can find other resources which has discussed about this constant